Cant install Solana CLI in WSL2 + Alpine
I followed the installion docs and Im getting this error /agave-install-init: not found
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.anza.xyz/stable/install)"
downloading stable installer
sh: /tmp/tmp.DaGNNc/agave-install-init: not found

